# Passing Personal Access Token in calling VSTS API

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, powershell-2.0, azure-devops-rest-api

I am using powershell to call VSTS API to query some `json data` for my build packages. I have no issues using `Invoke-RestMethod` to access the API but for the systems having power-shell 2.0 this cmdlet is not available and we are not authorized to install any higher version of powershell, hence I am using `$WebRequest = [System.Net.WebRequest]`. Is there any way I can pass my `VSTS PAT(personal access token)` to authenticate the web request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same basic process will work -- you base 64 encode your PAT, then add an Authorization header.

Something along these lines, for example:

```
$WebRequest = new-object System.Net.HttpWebRequest
$webrequest.Headers  = new-object System.Net.WebHeaderCollection
$WebRequest.Headers.Add('Authorization', 'Basic [your base64 encoded PAT]')
```